# SQL Server : function to calculate disjoint percentiles

Tags: sql-server, function

Since `ntile` might put the same number in more than one percentile, I use a query to calculate the percentile, using rank.

A table with data could be:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 
( score integer);

INSERT INTO #T1 (score) 
VALUES ('-1'), ('0'), ('0'), ('0'), ('2'), ('2'), ('3'), ('3'), ('4'), ('4'), ('6');
```

And the query is:

```
select 
    *, floor(5 * (rk- 1) / total) + 1 as q 
from 
    (select 
         *, 
         rank() over (partition by 1 order by score) as rk,
         count(*) over(partition by 1) as total 
     from #t1) z
```

I would like to create a FUNCTION that returns the percentile, so I can pass the table and the name of the column. In this case #t1 and score and returns q column.

I don't want to use a stored procedure.

Thanks,

Comment: And the problem you are running into is?

Comment: If you want to pass in the table's name as a a parameter there is only one choice: Dynamic SQL. And with this you'll have no way around a SP. The only workaround might be - in case you know all tables before - to use a huge `CASE` or `IF` or `UNION with COALESCE` structure. But to be honest. This won't work probably...

Comment: One idea: You might use a SP to transfer the needed data together with an `ActionID` into a dedicated table. Your function get's the `ActionID' as parameter and works against this one known table. With this approach you could eventually end up with a quite clean approach ...

Comment: Well you definitely can NOT do this with a function, because dynamic SQL is not allowed in functions.   Unless you want to write IF statements for every possible combination of table/column that you can want from the function.